# javascripts/jquery countdown giving wrong hours on mobile

Tags: jquery, countdown

I'm counting down to the eclipse using jquery countdown.js. Everything counts correctly on my desktop. On mobile (android), the countdown is one hour ahead. On other people's mobile, the countdown shows 0 hours. What am I doing wrong? Am I not accounting for timezone? Should that matter? The countdown is to the eclipse (less than 4 hours from now), so I could really use help quickly!

```
var date = new Date("2017-08-21T13:18:00"); //1:18 p.m. EST

 $("#dayElem")
  .countdown(date, function(event) {
    if (event.strftime('%-D') < 10) {
        $(this).text('0' +
          event.strftime('%-D')
        );
     } else {
        $(this).text(
          event.strftime('%-D')
        ); 
     }
  });

  $("#hourElem")
  .countdown(date, function(event) {
     if (event.strftime('%-H') < 10) {
        $(this).text('0' +
          event.strftime('%-H')
        );
     } else {
        $(this).text(
          event.strftime('%-H')
        ); 
     }
  });
   $("#minuteElem")
  .countdown(date, function(event) {
     if (event.strftime('%-M') < 10) {  
        $(this).text('0' +
          event.strftime('%-M')
        );
     } else {
        $(this).text(
          event.strftime('%-M')
        ); 
     }
  });
  $("#secondElem")
  .countdown(date, function(event) {

    if (event.strftime('%-S') < 10) {
        $(this).text('0' +
            event.strftime('%-S')
         ); 
      } else {
        $(this).text(
            event.strftime('%-S')
         ); 
      }

  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your assumption is correct. You have to account for the current timezone.
The easiest way to accomplish this is to use moment.js (https://momentjs.com/) and modify the code like this:

```
var date = moment.utc('2017-08-21T17:18:00').toDate();

$("#dayElem")
        .countdown(date, function (event) {
            if (event.strftime('%-D') < 10) {
                $(this).text('0' +
                        event.strftime('%-D')
                        );
            } else {
                $(this).text(
                        event.strftime('%-D')
                        );
            }
        });

$("#hourElem")
        .countdown(date, function (event) {
            if (event.strftime('%-H') < 10) {
                $(this).text('0' +
                        event.strftime('%-H')
                        );
            } else {
                $(this).text(
                        event.strftime('%-H')
                        );
            }
        });
$("#minuteElem")
        .countdown(date, function (event) {
            if (event.strftime('%-M') < 10) {
                $(this).text('0' +
                        event.strftime('%-M')
                        );
            } else {
                $(this).text(
                        event.strftime('%-M')
                        );
            }
        });
$("#secondElem")
        .countdown(date, function (event) {

            if (event.strftime('%-S') < 10) {
                $(this).text('0' +
                        event.strftime('%-S')
                        );
            } else {
                $(this).text(
                        event.strftime('%-S')
                        );
            }

        });
```

Also note that I specified the time in UTC instead of EST.

When running your code in my timezone, CET, I got only zeroes. When using the code above I got about 3 hours and 10 minutes at the time of posting this.